# How to create dataflow pipeline from JSON file on cloud storage to datastore

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Im new to GCP and needed some help on the following:
I have a .json file uploaded to cloud storage and need to move the data into cloud datastore for parsing/queries.

I think a large dataset may take too long to import natively, so was interesting in using dataflow to transform and load.
Any ideas or help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a fairly straightforward problem.  You'll need to:

1. Review the basics of writing dataflow pipelines here:
   https://beam.apache.org/documentation/pipelines/design-your-pipeline/
2. Read from GCS:
   https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/0.2.0-incubating/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.html
3. Transform JSON to entities:
   https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/coders/TableRowJsonCoder
   (or similar)
4. Write to Datastore
   https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/datastore

Hope this helps!